# Implement search filter on KendoTreeView with angular

Tags: angular, search, kendo-treeview

I have tried to implemented kendotreeview on json data. But I am unable to use filter using "filterable". Here is what so far I have done. Please help me with searching.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hbjccw-xkwehf?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Thanks for help

Comment: try upgrade the KendoTreeView library (It's looks like the version you use has no "filterable" property, but be carefull if the last version is compatible with your Angular version)

Comment: I tried upgrading the kendotreeview library version but not working.

Comment: Hi @Ludwig can I get your help please for implementing this functionality?